# Make a JavaScript function run after two or more events occur?

Tags: javascript, callback

My HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Foo</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The script `foo.js`:

```
function onEvent1(callback) {
  console.log('registered callback for first event')
  setTimeout(callback, 1000)
}

function onEvent2(callback) {
  console.log('registered callback for second event')
  setTimeout(callback, 2000)
}

function work() {
  console.log('work done')
}

function main() {
  var event1Done = false
  var event2Done = false
  var windowLoadDone = false

  onEvent1(function () {
    event1Done = true
    console.log('first event done')
  })

  onEvent2(function () {
    event2Done = true
    console.log('second event done')
  })

  window = {}
  window.onload = function() {
    windowLoadDone = true
    console.log('window load done')
  }

  function workInvoker() {
    // check
    if (event1Done && event2Done && windowLoadDone) {
      work()
    } else {
      // retry
      setTimeout(workInvoker, 1000)
    }
  }

  workInvoker()
}

main()
```

What I am trying to do: Ensure that `work()` runs only after three
events have occurred: `onEvent1`, `onEvent2`, and `window.onload`.

I have implemented `onEvent1` and `onEvent2` with `setTimeout` but it
could have any implementation that invokes the callback asynchronously.

Is there any JavaScript concept that would let me ensure that `work()`
is automatically invoked after the three events occur without me having
to hardcode it with the check-and-retry mechanism I have implemented in
`workInvoker()`?

Answer (score 2):

Just call `workInvoker` on every event?

```
function main() {
  var event1Done = false
  var event2Done = false
  var windowLoadDone = false

  onEvent1(function () {
    event1Done = true
    console.log('first event done')
    workInvoker()
  })

  onEvent2(function () {
    event2Done = true
    console.log('second event done')
    workInvoker()
  })

  window = {}
  window.onload = function() {
    windowLoadDone = true
    console.log('window load done')
    workInvoker()
  }

  function workInvoker() {
    // check
    if (event1Done && event2Done && windowLoadDone) {
      work()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started writing exactly what Felix wrote. So +1 to that. :D It would be shorter with a lookup object instead of local variables, but that's the manual approach.

You can do the same thing more cleanly with promises, using `Promise.all`, assuming your callbacks are promisified:

```
Promise.all(
  promiseOfEvent1,
  promiseOfEvent2,
  promiseOfWindowLoad
).then(results => {
  work();
})
```

where e.g.

```
const promiseOfWindowLoad = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  window.onload = resolve;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a counter variable that increases by 1 every time one of the three functions are invoked. When the value of the counter gets to 3 u may then execute the work() function i.e,if counter == 3   then function workInvoker() is executedelse it wont execute.

OR 
If you want to ensure that all the three are executed the you may use a global array with size 3 and assign 0 to all the three index values. Assign 0,1,2 to the three functions mentioned above which u want to execute.
If any of these functions is called u may then update its corresponding index value in global by 1. Then even if its called mutliple times, leave the index value as 1 only.
function workInvoker() will only execute when all the three index values of the global array are 1 and u can use a helper function that will check the index values of the global array.